# Is it possible to check whether -e is set within a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

If a shell function needs a specific setting of -e/+e in order to work, is it possible to set that setting locally and then restore it to its previous setting before exiting the function?

```
myfunction()
{
   # Query here if -e is set and remember in a variable?
   # Or push the settings to then pop at the end of the function?
   set +e
   dosomething
   doanotherthing
   # Restore -e/+e as appropriate, don't just do unconditional   set -e
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have the flags currently set in the variable `$-`, so you can preserve this
at the start of function and restore it after.

```
save=$-
...
if [[ $save =~ e ]]
then set -e
else set +e
fi
```

Comment: It should be noted that `$-` also works in `/bin/sh` and you probably don't need bashisms to parse it, just use e.g. globbing that `case` provides

Answer (score 5):

You can read the flag value thru the variable SHELLOPTS:

```
  > set +e 
  > echo $SHELLOPTS
    braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor
  > set -e 
  > echo $SHELLOPTS
    braceexpand:emacs:errexit:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor
```

You see that, after setting `set -e`, the value `errexit` in `$SHELLOPTS` appears. You can check it from there.

However, you can get around this (if you wish!) by remembering the following point: according to [the Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html):

> **-e**:
>
> ..... 
>   This option applies to the shell environment and each subshell environment separately.

Thus, if you execute your function in a subshell, like

```
   zz="$(myfunction)"
```

you do not have to worry whether the `errexit` variable is set or not in calling environment, and you may set it as you like.

Comment: Thanks, SHELLOPTS is useful to be aware of. I do find $- suggested by @meuh easier to check programmatically though, that's why I accepted that answer.

Comment: The note about subshells is useful too, but I wanted to avoid modifying the call sites. Otherwise I would probably change `myfunction` calls to `myfunction || true` to suppress the effect of -e for the calls and not have to do `set +e` inside the function in the first place.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: 20000 congratulations.

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to use the `shopt` builtin (with the `-o` flag, to access the right set of options, from `set -o`; and the `-q` flag, to just quietly provide the setting via the exit code from `shopt`).  So, something like this:

```
# save the previous "set -e" setting
shopt -oq errexit && set_e_used=$? || set_e_used=$?
set +e

...your code here...

# restore the previous "set -e" setting
if [[ $set_e_used -eq 0 ]]; then
    set -e
else
    set +e
fi
```