# In a bash script, how do I check if "-e" is set?

Tags: bash, exit-code

I use `set -e` in scripts quite often, but sometimes, it's ok for a script to fail in some of it's commands.
I tried checking if `set -e` was ON, but couldn't find a way to do it - there's no option (that I know of) in `set` that will provide the current value.
Also tried this:
`set | grep errexit` (`errexit` is the option name for `-e`) and `set | grep "-e"`, no luck there.
I would like to check if the `errexit` option is set, so I could temporarily disable it in some of my library functions that I built over time (using `set +e` and re-applying `set -e` if needed).
Something like:

```sh
if [ errexit is set ]; then
   ERR_EXIT=1
   set +e
fi
...
run some code that may fail
...
if [ "${ERR_EXIT}" = 1 ]; then
    set -e
fi
```

Comment: This doesn't strictly answer your question, but remember you can always do things like `cmd || true` to stop the script from exiting if `cmd` fails, or even better: you can make `cmd` the subject of an `if` statement that deals with its failure.

Comment: Thanks @IzaakvanDongen ,I know that, it doesn’t help when the main script uses ‘-e‘ and some library function I wrote years ago explicitly checks ‘$?‘

Comment: Also: https://superuser.com/questions/997755/is-it-possible-to-check-whether-e-is-set-within-a-bash-script/997776, https://superuser.com/questions/1034770/how-to-check-shell-options,

Comment: Thanks @muru ! Already using glenn-jackman 's answer, but user1686 and the answers you pointed out are also correct.

Comment: For your particular case, you can do `local restore_errexit="$(shopt -po errexit)"`.  The command outputs the code needed to set it back to what it is now.  To restore, all you have to do is just run `${restore_errexit}`.  To just save and restore, it's the most simple way.

Comment: Also, to control IF statements in general, you can do `if shopt -q -o errexit ; then echo "it's on" ; fi` since the command's exit code will tell you if the option is set or not and `-q` for quiet makes it not output anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You check if the `$-` variable contains `e`

```
if [[ $- == *e* ]]
```

See [Special-Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters) in the manual.

---

For POSIX shells, `case` is the builtin tool for pattern matching

```sh
case $- in
*e*) doSomething ;;
esac
```

Comment: You might want to read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 for some interesting discussion about the use of `set -e`

Answer (score 3):

Within **bash** (but not basic sh), you can use `shopt -o -p errexit`. Its output can be stored and later eval'd to restore the initial value. (It will also return 0 if the option is set, 1 otherwise.)

errexit will also not trigger in several cases even if enabled, such as if the failing command was used together with `||` – for example `this_can_fail || true` will let you ignore just that command.

It will also not trigger if the command was part of an `if` condition, e.g. `if ! this_can_fail; then echo "Warning: it failed"; fi`.